# Explain Validate Transaction Proof Method Parameters

Tags: python, validation, transactions, web3py, evm

This is [url](https://www.bscscan.com/tx/0x9da5f86035fee778724a10ab13c2ce76c67ce1f8f81df522cffe1a52351185cd) of a transaction on bscscan. I want to simulate this transaction with web3.py. In "Input Data", I don't understand value "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ba1". What is it ? where can I get it from ? I convert this hex string to number , result is 2977. It's not NFT id , please help me. Thank you